# Offset overlapping lines in multiple vector layers in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, angular

I have a feature in the Angular application where user can chose a layer to be drawn on map. Multiple layers with overlapping lines can be drawn at the same time. I use a dynamically created `VectorLayer` object for this, each with its own style and `Feature` updater based on a current `bBox`.

```typescript
export class DynamicVectorLayer {
// members declarations

// type FeaturesCollection = Array<Feature<Geometry>>;
constructor(features: FeaturesCollection, style: any) {
  this._vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    features,
    format: geoJsonFormat,
    strategy: bbox,
  });
  this._vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: this._vectorSource,
    style
  });
}

// Exposed method to update Layer's features
public updateFeatures(features: FeaturesCollection): void {
  this._vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
}
//...
}
```

Displayed lines are colored with a color provided as a parameter from Database. For that I created little helper function:

```
private procesLayerStyle(color: string): Style {
  const basicStyle = Styles.segment.standard.clone();
  const stroke = basicStyle.getStroke();

  stroke.setColor(color);
  stroke.setWidth(6);

  basicStyle.setStroke(stroke);
  return basicStyle;
}
```

My question is, where to handle overlapping lines? Is it something I can add to the `Style`? Do I have to handle it in a VectorLayer/VectorSource or somewhere else completely? As a OpenLayers newbie I'm bit lost with this. I don't know if OpenLayers offers ability for this, all I know is that `Features` object coming from DB is bit to complicated for a FE processing. And there can be many of them at the same time.

Note: I'm using  OpenLayers lib in version > 7.1: `"ol": "^7.1.0"`

Comment: You can style with a translated geometry as in https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-label-decluttering-forked-f5q6gq?file=/main.js but you would need to be able to identify overlapping features.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Comment: @Mike Offseting with translate does not work OK with lines at 45° angle. I would rather use `turf.lineOffset` method.

Comment: Yes, an example with polygons was not very appropriate for this.  In most case translate will work for a LineString if you take the angle of the line into account when calculating the translation https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-label-decluttering-forked-dmcqhp?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks again for ideas, look like we're going to offset whole layers by default. Calculating intersections on hundreds of segments might kill browser I'm afraid